# Universal object

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

I'm trying to define the concept of universal object in category theory, but I failed to find a universal way to do it. Maybe someone can help ?

THe idea is quite simple. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, and call $U$ universal if for all objects $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$, there exists a monic map from $A$ to $U$. That is, all objects inject inside $U$. I don't know if this definition is the good one, but that's the idea.

Example: $\mathbb{N}$ is the universal object of countable set. $(\mathbb{Q}, \leq)$ is the universal object of countable totally ordered sets, and so on.

Comment: Do you just want a monic map to exist, or do you want to have actually chosen a specific monic map for every object?

Comment: Text of the question doesn’t make sense, but the thing original poster is looking for is possibly “initial and terminal objects”.

Comment: Universal arrows with domains, perhaps?

Comment: @Incnis: I think the OP is looking more for an object in the category to play the role of the "universe"; e.g. in a lattice with a maximum element, you can think of the maximum as being the universe, and all other objects represent subobjects of the universe.

Comment: Yes this is exactly that Hurkyl. I think there's a way to define the object for a given set of monic maps for all objects, but I would like it to be isomorphic by change of monic maps obviously (so it is enough that just one monic map exists).

Comment: For motivations, notice that $\emptyset$ is co-universal in Sets (which means that it "creates" everyone). Can we find an object that is both universal and co-universal in some meaningful categories ? (I disregard the category of countable sets minus empty set to be a meaningful category here)

Comment: In the category of groups that can be presented by a set $S$ of cardinal $|S|$, the free group $F(S)$ over $S$ is co-universal.

Comment: In the category of countable pointed set, $(\mathbb{N},a)$ is both universal and co-universal. Call it divine object ;>.

Comment: In studying something like class theories the "every object injects into it" is pretty standard. See Colin McLarty's paper about Cartesian closedness failing in NF, or the definition of a universe in algebraic set theory. There may be finer notions that are handy in different contexts, though.

Answer (score 9):

Something to be aware of: using "universal object" to mean "an object into which every other object embeds" is not uncommon in areas outside of category theory (one hears of universal graphs, universal metric spaces, universal Polish spaces, ...), but note that within category theory, "universal object" strongly connotes that the "universality" property should characterize the object up to canonical isomorphism, a connotation which doesn't apply in the "embedding sense".

The adequacy of your definition will depend on what sort of examples you're trying to capture. Let me guess that the Rado graph (as a universal countable graph), the Urysohn universal space (as a universal separable metric space), and Hilbert Cube (as a universal Polish space) are some examples you want to include. Notice that requiring $A \to U$ to be monic is not enough in these examples: for instance, a monomorphism of graphs is a subgraph, but the fact that the Rado graph contains every countable graph as a subgraph is not as interesting as the fact that it contains every countable graph as an *induced* subgraph.

So you want to require that there is an "embedding" $A \to U$ for every object $A$. But it's not clear that there's a single categorical meaning of "embedding" that will be the interesting one in every case: it may depend on the category. Some discussion of the notion of "embedding" in category theory can be found in [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Category_theory), and [The Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/) to which it refers should have more information.

**ADDENDUM:** I wrote the above about two years ago, and I only just learned something more about this subject, largely from [Trevor Irwin's thesis](http://gradworks.umi.com/32/97/3297082.html), which gives a categorical treatment of [Fraïssé limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_(model_theory)), a construction which can be used to construct the random graph, for example.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and let $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ be a full subcategory.

- We say that $X \in \mathcal{C}$ is *$\mathcal{F}$-universal* if every $F \in \mathcal{F}$ admits a morphism $F \to X$.
- We say that $X \in \mathcal{C}$ is *$\mathcal{F}$-injective* if for every $F' \leftarrow F \to X$ with $F,F' \in \mathcal{F}$ there exists $F' \to X$ making a commutative triangle.
- We say that $X \in \mathcal{C}$ is *$\mathcal{F}$-homogeneous* if for every $X \leftarrow F \to X$ with $F \in \mathcal{F}$, there is an automorphism $X \cong X$ making a commutative triangle.

Now suppose that

1. $\mathcal{C}$ has colimits of ($\mathbb{N}$-indexed) chains $C_0 \to C_1\to \dots$ (equivalently, $\mathcal{C}$ has countable filtered colimits).
2. $\mathcal{F}$ has the property that if $f: F \to \varinjlim C_i$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ from an object $F \in \mathcal{F}$ to a colimit $\varinjlim C_i$ of a chain $C_0 \to C_1 \to \dots$ in $\mathcal{C}$, then $f$ factors through some $C_i$ (this follows if every $F \in \mathcal{F}$ is [finitely presentable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object)).

**Proposition.**
If (1) and (2) hold and $X \in \mathcal{C}$ is a colimit of a chain of objects of $\mathcal{F}$, then the following are equivalent and characterize $X$ up to isomorphism:

(i.) $X$ is $\omega\mathcal{F}$-universal and $\mathcal{F}$-homogeneous

(ii.) $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-universal and $\mathcal{F}$-homogeneous

(iii.) $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-universal and $\mathcal{F}$-injective.

Here $\omega \mathcal{F}$ denotes the closure of $\mathcal{F}$ under colimits of chains.

**Proof.** (i.) -> (ii.) is trivial. (ii.) -> (iii.) requires just a moment's thought. (iii.) -> (ii.) uses a [back-and-forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method) argument, inductively building up both directions of an isomorphism, working up the chain defining $X$. (iii.) -> (i.) is easy. The fact that (iii.) characterizes $X$ up to isomorphism use another back-and-forth argument.

Let's call an $X$ satisfying the equivalent condtions of the proposition *$\mathcal{F}$-saturated*. We can get existence of such an $X$ with some mild additional conditions on $\mathcal{F}$:

3. $\mathcal{F}$ has the [joint embedding property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_embedding_property): any pair of objects $F_1, F_2 \in \mathcal{F}$, admit a cocone, i.e. there is a diagram $F_1 \to F_3 \leftarrow F_2$ in $\mathcal{F}$.
4. $\mathcal{F}$ has the [amalgamation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amalgamation_property): any span $F_1 \leftarrow F_0 \to F_2$ in $\mathcal{F}$ admits a cocone, i.e. it can be completed to a commutative square like

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F_0 @>>> F_1\\
@VVV @VVV \\
F_2 @>>> F_3
\end{CD}
$

**Theorem.** If (1,2,3,4) hold and $\mathcal{F}$ is essentially countable then there exists an $\mathcal{F}$-saturated object $X \in \mathcal{C}$ which is a colimit of a chain of objects of $\mathcal{F}$. Conversely, if there exists an $X \in \mathcal{C}$ which is $\mathcal{F}$-injective and $\mathcal{F}$-universal, and which is a colimit of a chain of objects of $\mathcal{C}$ and (2) holds, then (3,4) hold.

**Proof.**
We construct a chain $X_0 \to X_1 \to \dots$ whose colimit is will be $X$. The idea is to solve the lifting problems of $\mathcal{F}$-universality and $\mathcal{F}$-injectivity by using (3) and (4) to extend the chain with solutions to these lifting problems. Then since any lifting problem must factor through a finite stage of the chain, it can be solved at a finite stage and thus be solved in the colimit. Some care must be taken in doing this, see Irwin's thesis or another reference on the Fraïssé construction. The "conversely" statement takes just a moment's reflection.

When we take $\mathcal{C}$ to be the category of graphs and embeddings and $\mathcal{F}$ to be the subcategory of finite graphs, we construct the Rado graph this way, and similarly other Fraïssé limits. When we take $\mathcal{C}$ to be the category of complete metric spaces and isometric embeddings and $\mathcal{F}$ to be the subcategory of finite metric spaces with rational distances, we construct the Urysohn universal space this way.

Everything generalizes easily to cardinalities $\kappa$ larger than countable -- in (1) $\mathcal{C}$ will have to be closed under colimits of chains of length $\leq \kappa$, while in (2), $\mathcal{F}$ will have to have this property with respect to chains of length $\kappa$ and moreover be closed under colimits of chains of length less than $\kappa$. (3) and (4) require no modification. In the existence theorem we require that $\mathcal{F}$ have size essentially $\leq \kappa$. By taking $\mathcal{C}$ to be the category of models of a first-order theory and $\mathcal{F}$ to be the models of size $< \kappa$, we recover the construction of [saturated models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_model) in the usual sense in model theory, with the usual set-theoretical provisos.

I haven't checked whether this theorem applies to give a construction of the Hilbert cube.

The construction will be somewhat degenerate in a category where morphisms are not monic -- think about what $\mathcal{F}$-injectivity means in this case. So $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ might be non-full subcategories of a category that you're primarily interested in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these interesting references

Comment: You're welcome :). Another point to think about is that "size restrictions" are essential when looking for universal objects: for example there is no universal graph and no universal _finite_ graph, but there is a universal _countable_ graph. On the other hand, it's already somewhat interesting that every _finite_ graph embeds in the Rado graph, even though the Rado graph is not finite: to get universality, you have to leave the category of finite graphs that you might start with.

Comment: Yes, and the same thing happens for co-universal objects as far as I understand (see my example about free countable groups). I think it should be interesting to give some example of objects that are both universal and co-universal (in the sense of embedding and surjection/image of some maps).

Comment: Another thing about rado is that any embedding can be extended to another embedding.

Comment: I've seen (in categorical logic) a universal object in a category defined as an object such that all objects in the category are a retract of it. Does this capture the various examples mentioned here?